# request failed with status code 422 is returned by axios delete in react.js

Tags: reactjs

I list some room_name from the backend with React.js

What I want to implement is that user can delete room_name when user clicks the trash can icon.

**Issue/error message**

```
Request failed with status code 422
```

It's strange
As shown in the picture, I can see "the body sent to server section" on the console.

[image]

I can confirm that the room_name has been sent properly.
I believe the data you are sending is correct.

Even if I try with Postman with the same URL and data, I can delete it successfully.

[image]

```
const SettingGetRoomName = () => {

  const [room_name, setRoomName] = useState([]);


   const DeleteRoom = async(data) => {
    console.log("Body sent to server", {
    home_rooms: [data.item], 
  })
    await axios.delete("xxx.com",
      {
        home_rooms: [data.item], 
      },
      {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': `Bearer ${cookies.get('accesstoken')}`
        },
      })
      .then(result => {
        alert('Succeded delete room!');
        console.log('Succeded delete room!');
      })
      .catch(err => {
        alert('Missed delete room!');
        console.log(err);
        console.log('Missed delete room!');
      });
  }

  const getRoomName = async(data) => {
    await axios.get("xxx.com",
      {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': `Bearer ${cookies.get('accesstoken')}`
        },
      })
      .then(result => {
        console.log(result.data)
        setRoomName(result.data.home_rooms);  
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }



  useEffect(() => {
    getRoomName();
  },[]);




  return (
    <>

            {room_name.map((item,i) => 
              <div key={i}  className="flex_setting_get_room_box">
                  <div className="my_hubs">
                    <p className="">{item}</p>
                    <img src={ic_delete} onClick={(e)=>DeleteRoom({item})}/>
                  </div>
              </div>
            )}

    </>
  );
}
export default SettingGetRoomName;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this [link](https://masteringjs.io/tutorials/axios/delete) and the [axios docs](https://axios-http.com/docs/api_intro). The second parameter of `axios.delete()` is not the request body, but rather the request options. Simply add the body on the `data` key of the request options:

```
 await axios.delete("xxx.com", {
        data: {
            home_rooms: [data.item]
        },
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${cookies.get('accesstoken')}`
        },
    })
    .then(result => {
        alert('Succeded delete room!');
        console.log('Succeded delete room!');
    })
    .catch(err => {
        alert('Missed delete room!');
        console.log(err);
        console.log('Missed delete room!');
    });
```